# Apply working Shell code in a different database

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access

I have used the "Shell" function, in other Access databases, to open folders.
With the same code structure I get the

> 5 error code of "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Using shell function as follows:

```vb
    Dim FreightFile_Path As String
    FreightFile_Path = "S:\Supply Chain\Freight"
    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & FreightFile_Path, vbNormalFocus
```

I tried the double quotes and Chr(34)'s around them.
I copied the code from one database (that it worked in) to another and it error-ed.

Am I missing something I need to activate in MS Access? I checked the references in VBA and made sure they match.

Things I tried:

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & Chr(34) & "S:\Shared" & Chr(34), 
vbNormalFocus)
```

```
Shell "explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & FreightFile_Path & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
```

```
Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & FreightFile_Path, vbNormalFocus
```

```
Dim retVal
retVal = Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & FreightFile_Path, vbNormalNoFocus)
```

```
Dim i As String
i = "explorer.exe" & " " & FreightFile_Path
Shell i, vbNormalFocus
```

```
FreightFile_Path = "S:\Supply Chain\Freight"
Shell "explorer.exe " & FreightFile_Path, vbNormalFocus
```

Restarted the application, restarted the computer.

Comment: It is just a string to a folder. I have literally set it to just "S:\Supply Chain\Freight" for testing purposes. I dont really want to open a specific file like a pdf or an excel document because there will be multiple in this folder.

I have also tried using the full server path and that didnt work either

Comment: The code in the top snippet works perfectly fine here, ...given a valid path, with or without spaces in it. Is the `S` drive a mapped network drive? (should work fine too) - I can't repro the error 5 you're getting, even with an invalid path (it opens "my documents")

Comment: FWIW the `Shell` function is defined in the `VBA.Interaction` module; it's in the VBA standard library, just like `MsgBox`. No "special references" are needed.

Comment: I realize it is very strange. I have another database on the same computer that the same exact code works perfectly fine. I am just wondering if I dont have a setting activated or something that is preventing it from working

Comment: Stupid question: does the project compile? Debug ~> Compile VBAProject

Comment: Yep, everything is compiled. Here is a photo of the code side by side. If you just look at the highlighted areas that is what is running (Rest of stuff would work if I wasnt testing). But it works on one and not the other

https://imgur.com/YUpVQAW

Saw i had the call shell not commented out, but still - commented out that line and same result

Comment: Is it possible that the symbol `Shell` has been redefined elsewhere in the database?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm having the exact same problem: `Shell` works in one database but not another.  My test is as simple as it gets: `Shell "notepad.exe"`.  The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676948/access-vba-shell-command-broken-in-one-particular-database

Comment: Only instance of `Shell` is the single time i use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem.  In my case, it turned out to be anti-virus that was blocking `Shell`.  It just so happened that IT had put exceptions in place for my computer for one database but not the other.  See [my question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56691523/5405967) for more detail.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you

Comment: @goldgerm Sweet!  It's so weird how we both had the same strange problem on the same day.  Glad it worked out :)

Comment: Very much so. It was driving me nuts! Between the 2 databases it was literally THE. SAME. CODE. and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FreightFile_Path = "S:\Supply Chain\Freight"
Shell "cmd /c start explorer.exe """ & FreightFile_Path & """"
```

It is a bit of a workaround, but it works...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately no dice. Still got the error 5

What's strange is I paste that into a different database and it works just fine, I wonder if i just have a corrupt access file...

Answer (score 0):

New try. Use a WinAPI call

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal lpnShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Sub ShellEx(ByVal Path As String, Optional ByVal Parameters As String, Optional ByVal HideWindow As Boolean)
    If Dir(Path) > "" Then
        ShellExecute 0, "open", Path, Parameters, "", IIf(HideWindow, 0, 1)
    End If
End Sub

Sub Test()
    FreightFile_Path = "S:\Supply Chain\Freight"
    ShellEx "c:\windows\explorer.exe", """" & FreightFile_Path & """"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for the help. This might not really be an answer to the `Shell` problem, but it will work for opening a file path.

```
Dim FreightFilePath As String
FreightFilePath = "S:\Supply Chain\Freight"
Application.FollowHyperLink FreightFilePath
```