# Access VBA: Shell command broken in one particular database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two Access databases that I'm opening on the same computer.  In one, running this in the immediate window works as expected (opens Notepad):

```
Shell "notepad.exe"
```

In the other, I get this error instead:

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

I have not been able to come up with any shell command that will run successfully in that second database. No matter what, I get that error.

What is going on here?  Could there be a security setting coming into play?  Or perhaps one is an older version?

### Edit - More Info

- When I go to the definition of `Shell` in the malfunctioning database, it goes to `VBA.Interaction.Shell`.
- I get the correct IntelliSense tooltip for `Shell`.
- I tried `VBA.Shell "notepad.exe"` and `VBA.Interaction.Shell "notepad.exe"` without success (same error).
- Here are the references that are checked in both databases:

  [image]
- Decompiling did not help.

Comment: Just two ideas: 1. Is there any code being executed on startup? 2. Take a look in the references of the database. Maybe there is something orphaned?

Comment: May be there is redefenition of `Shell` function in the second database. Try to press `Ctrl + F2` at 'Shell' in Immediate window to jump to definition.

Comment: Or be explicit and try `VBA.Shell` which will force the VBA library to be used.

Comment: @UnhandledException There's no Autoexec macro defined - if that's what you mean.  See my edit regarding the references.

Comment: @4dmonster When I go to the definition of `Shell` in the malfunctioning database, it goes to `VBA.Interaction.Shell`.

Comment: @Gareth I tried `VBA.Shell "notepad.exe"` and `VBA.Interaction.Shell "notepad.exe"` without success (same error).

Comment: You could try a full [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271). -- Also, if you type `Shell ` in the faulty db, does it show the correct Intellisense tooltip?

Comment: @Andre I just tried decompiling per the instructions in that link.  I still get the same error afterward.  IntelliSense works as expected now and did before as well.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was our anti-virus software!  **UGH!**

Why did it work in one database and not the other then?  I'm told that years ago, anti-virus exceptions were made for my computer for the one database but not the other.

I recommend that any others who encounter this problem check their anti-virus logs/policies.  Also, running the database from another computer with different policies in place might shed some light on the issue faster.  In this case, when I used remote desktop to log into a server, I was able to call shell successfully.